# Aligning textfields close together produces inaccurate spacing appearance

Tags: actionscript-3

I've added Arial as an embedded font to my font format, which I've added to numerous textfields that must be aligned accurately next to each other to create the appearance of spaces. They are aligned approximately 1 - 2 pixels next to each other. The problem is that they look inaccurately spaced when viewed at the normal stage size, but when I zoom in the text looks fine.

I've tried messing around and adding advanced antialiasing, but nothing is working. Perhaps Arial doesn't work at small sizes? I know not setting a font it produces the results I want, however it's not the font I want to use; it must be using Times?

Any ideas?

```
var myFont = new Font1();

            format1 = new TextFormat(); 
            format1.color = 0x000000; 
            format1.size = 16;
        format1.font = myFont.fontName;
```

EDIT:
Essentially I'm splitting up each character into its own textfield, so I can manipulate each character and animate it. But to do so I need to space the characters as though it was one textfield.

```
private var bmd:BitmapData; // bitmapdata to draw textField in;
        private function getExactMetrics(textField:TextField):Object
        {
            // copy textField to bitmap
            bmd = new BitmapData(textField.width,textField.height,true,0x000000);
            bmd.draw(textField);

            // loop through pixels of bitmap data and store the x location of pixels found.
            var foundx:Array = [];

             for (var nx:int = 0; nx < bmd.width;nx++)
               {
                for (var ny:int = 0; ny < bmd.height; ny++)
                {

                    var px:uint = bmd.getPixel32(nx, ny);
                    if (px != 0)
                    {
                        foundx.push(nx);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

            // get the values for the metrics
            var startX:int = foundx[0]; // first pixel found representing the x start of the text in pixels
            var endX:int = foundx[foundx.length-1]; t
            var realWidth:Number = endX - startX; 

            // clear the array with found x positions
            foundx = [];

            // wrap values in object
            var metrics:Object = { };
            metrics.width = realWidth;
            metrics.x = startX;

            // clear bitmapdata
            bmd = null;

            return metrics; // retrurn metric object;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that fonts have `kerning` which means that letters are not just put one next to each other, but spacing depends on settings of the font. For example in word 'To' 'o' is slightly below the 'top beam' of letter 'T'.

If you just put letter next to each other it will look bad, you have to consider kerning.

`TextField` class has a `getCharBoundaries` method which can be used to get accurate char position. Not sure if it will work with htmlText, though.

To make it simpler you could use a third party library. There is a great [SplitTextField](http://www.greensock.com/splittextfield/) from Greensock (but it's not free) or [Textanim](http://code.google.com/p/textanim/) (open source).

Comment: getCharBoundaries!!! I can't believe I was calculating pixels when this function included the kerning automatically. Thanks

Comment: Actually, the kerning is a bit off if I split every character in its own textfield, but it's better than what I had before

Answer (score 0):

Fonts such as Verdana might have greater readability at smaller sizes; however, it sounds like you are experiencing text metrics issues.

In this example, TextLineMetrics are used to accurately measure each text field.

Result:

[image: text line metrics]

Code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    import flash.text.Font;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.text.TextLineMetrics;

    [SWF(percentWidth = 100, percentHeight = 100, backgroundColor = 0xefefef, frameRate = 30)]
    public class X extends Sprite
    {

        public function X()
        {
            super();

            // collection of words
            var words:Array = [ "These", "are", "the", "words", "to", "be", "placed" ];

            // define a text format
            var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            textFormat.font = "Arial";
            textFormat.bold = false;
            textFormat.size = 8;
            textFormat.color = 0x0;
            textFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;

            // destination x coordinate for next word text field
            var dx:Number = 0;

            // for every word
            for each (var word:String in words)
            {
                // create a text field
                var textField:TextField = new TextField();
                textField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
                textField.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
                textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

                // set text and place the text field
                textField.text = word;
                textField.x = dx;
                textField.y = 20;
                addChild(textField);

                // measure the text field for accurate width
                var textLineMetrics:TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
                dx += textLineMetrics.width + 2;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using getPixel32 and getting accurate character width etc... It looks fine when I zoom in, make text larger, or make the space larger.  I'll try verdana

Comment: If you're actually using getPixel32, make sure you're sampling full line height and accounting for anti aliasing.  Maybe all you really need is fine tuning to kerning.

Comment: I posted the function im using. How do I account for anti aliasing?